# Some confusion of utf8 in Linux server?

Tags: linux, utf-8, locale

About character set I always have question.

Local (Mac OS)

```
bash-3.2$ 你好
bash: 你好: command not found
bash-3.2$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Linux Server (ssh)

```
root@hg:~# 你好
-bash: $'\344\275\240\345\245\275': command not found
root@hg:~# locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

#### Question 1

Why both are utf8, in Server `你好` changed to `\344\275\240\345\245\275` but literal `你好`?

#### Question 2

Dose `\344\275\240\345\245\275` represents `utf-8` encode of `你好`? Should it be `\xE4\xBD\xA0\xE5\xA5\xBD`? Are there different `utf-8`?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why both are utf8, in Server 你好 changed to \344\275\240\345\245\275 but literal 你好?

The display comes from your shell. Locally you're using `zsh` which just copies your input in the error message.

Remotely, you're using `bash` which tries to make sure the message is displayed even if you're missing the right fonts, so it converts each byte to octal representation.

> Does \344\275\240\345\245\275 represents utf-8 encode of 你好? Should it be \xE4\xBD\xA0\xE5\xA5\xBD? Are there different utf-8?

The first is octal representation. Octal `344` is hex `e4`. All bytes match, it's just a different display format.

Comment: Thanks! but when I changed to bash(`exec bash`) in local, it still outputs literal `你好`.

Comment: Which version of bash are you using? The printable filenames only got added in 4.2 (and improved in 4.4, not sure what the behaviour in 4.2/4.3 is)